# How to adjust all content of website in half screen vertically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have 2 main sections inside body tag top of each others that contains 50vh. But inside those 2 sections there is a large content that is overflowing right now. I want to adjust  that content so it remains 50% of screen height. How can I do that? Does css zoom property can help? If yes then how I will determine its value?
See screenshot below How can I adjust all content to not overflow that red area also there can be 10 image boxes so they may appear in multiple lines, in that case what will I do? When I use zoom css property to red box It got fixed but how I will know what value I should give to that red box?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Without any code provideed, it is difficult to give you the best answer.

If the element overflowing your 50vh height section is a div, it is not possible to adjust its size on applying a css rule on the container. I wan think of 2 way of helping:

- applying a proportionnal height on the overflowing element: `height: 50%` (or `max-height`)
- adding an overflow or overflow-y property (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/overflow))

Comment: ! Can you please look at this?